# UART communication bet controller and smart card reader over UART

Tags: uart

I am newbie to UART interface. My query is, in my application, smart card reader is interfaced with controller LPC2138 over UART interface.

Connection scheme:

uP ( TxD) --> reader (RxD)

uP ( RxD) --> reader (TxD)

I want to trap these (RxD,TxD) signals on hyper terminal, if I connect MAX232 to UART pins and if while communication bet uP and reader, MAX232 is interafced on same lines.. Is it possible ? Can I trap signals?

Comment: Yes connecting Max232 will work. Few months back I was working on GSM so I used the MAX232 to see the data transmission between Micro Controller and GSM module.

Comment: You should reverse the 2. arrow pointing in the direction of data flow.

Comment: Thanks for answer. @Martin, I'm not getting abt pin reversal you mentioned. For MAX interface, If I connect TxD to T1IN, RxD to R1Out, T1Out to Pin 2 of DB9 and R1IN to pin3, Is it correct?

Comment: Maybe i misunderstood your question. You want to look at the communication between uP and reader, right? Do you want to place your PC/laptop in between? This would require two serial ports. Or do you just want to connect to the existing wires?

Comment: I want to use same lines for MAX232. I am basically trapping(reading) UART signals.

Comment: Are you just trying to watch the data between the uP and the card reader with a MAX232 connected to your laptop?

Comment: Yes. @ Dean. I am trying same.

Comment: I updated my answer. I hope I understood your question right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: After some clarification...

The intended setup is only possible with two serial ports on the PC/laptop.

The MAX232 has two amplifiers to convert from the CMOS/TTL voltage level (wire to observe) to the RS232 voltage levels of the serial cable. But, the serial port of the PC/laptop (aka. DTE) has only one receive data pin (`RXD`, pin 2 at DE-9 connector of the DTE). The other data pin (`TXD`) is driven in the opposite, and thus wrong, direction.

The wire to observe must be connected to the `T1IN` (pin 11) or `T2IN` (pin 10) [input of the MAX232](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/max232.pdf). The level-shifted outputs are then `T1OUT` (pin 14) and `T2OUT` (pin 7), respectively. One of these outputs must then be connected to pin 9 of the DE-9 connector of the DTE.

This is also a sort of a [null modem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_modem) link. Thus, one must connect `DTR` (pin 4) to `DSR` (pin 6) and `DCD` (pin 1). As well as `RTS` (pin 7) to `CTS` (pin 8). All pin numbers are given of the DE-9 connector of the DTE.